# Alterar o título e as cores da legenda no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como faço para alterar o campo `pop` e `continent`. Quero colocar em português (População e Continente). Os dados estão no *R* através do pacote *library(gapminder)*.

Utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
gapminder_2007 <- filter(.data=gapminder,year==2007)
ggplot(data=gapminder_2007,aes(x=gdpPercap,y=lifeExp,color=continent,size=pop)) + 
   labs(title="PIB e Expectativa de Vida em 2007", subtitle="", 
   y="Expectativa de Vida",x="PIB Per capita", caption="") +
   geom_point() + 
   scale_x_log10()
```

Resultado:

[image: img]

Answer (score 4):

Use os argumentos `color` e `size` dentro da função `labs`:

```
ggplot(data=gapminder_2007,aes(x=gdpPercap,y=lifeExp,color=continent,size=pop)) + 
  labs(title="PIB e Expectativa de Vida em 2007", subtitle="", 
       y="Expectativa de Vida",x="PIB Per capita", caption="",
       color = "Continente",
       size = "População") +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

Ou

```
ggplot(data=gapminder_2007,aes(x=gdpPercap,y=lifeExp,color=continent,size=pop)) + 
  labs(title="PIB e Expectativa de Vida em 2007", subtitle="", 
       y="Expectativa de Vida",x="PIB Per capita", caption="") +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10() + 
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Continente")) + # Argumentos para os títulos das legendas
  guides(size=guide_legend(title="População"))
```

**Edição: Escolher as cores dos países:**
Para alterar as cores do país você pode usar qualquer opção do `scale_color_****`

- `scale` refere-se ao nome da função para realizar alterações de
  cores; `
- color`refere-se ao nome do argumento que você colocou no`aes` que tu quer alterar;
- `*****` refere-se ao modo que você quer    informar as cores. Você
  pode passar os valores da forma [`manual`](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour), [`brewer`](http://colorbrewer2.org/), e demais formas (essas são as principais/quais eu uso).

Na opção **manual**, você deve informar os nomes das cores manualmente:

```
ggplot(data=gapminder_2007,aes(x=gdpPercap,y=lifeExp,color=continent,size=pop)) + 
  labs(title="PIB e Expectativa de Vida em 2007", subtitle="", 
       y="Expectativa de Vida",x="PIB Per capita", caption="",
       color = "Continente",
       size = "População") +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red", "yellow", "gray11", "blue")) #Informa aqui as cores!
```

Usando a paleta de cor `Spectral` de `color brewer`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ggplot(data=gapminder_2007,aes(x=gdpPercap,y=lifeExp,color=continent,size=pop)) + 
  labs(title="PIB e Expectativa de Vida em 2007", subtitle="", 
       y="Expectativa de Vida",x="PIB Per capita", caption="",
       color = "Continente",
       size = "População") +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de trocar as cores por continente no gráfico?

Comment: Questão editada. Favor, marcar como aceita a resposta se ela funcionou para ti.